# No method error - save from rubystutorial.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, save, nomethoderror

I've been following along Hartl's book at rubystutorial.org and stuck on this error

When I run rspec tests it tells me that the method (save) does not exist for user

Here's my code and test. I can't find what's wrong with it and why the method doesn't exist within @user

user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com") 
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid } 
  end

  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "shoud be invalid" do 
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo. foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        expect(@user).not_to be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do 
    it "should be valid" do 
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        expect(@user).to be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email address is already taken" do 
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

end
```

And my user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    validates(:name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 } )
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates(:email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false } )
end
```

Exact error is

```
Failures:

1) User when email address is already taken 

 Failure/Error: user_with_same_email.save
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `save' for "USER@EXAMPLE.COM":String
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:55:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.411 seconds
24 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:58 # User when email address is already take
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are defining a user and then change it on string (email, so email has no save method) in the next lines:

```
user_with_same_email = @user.dup
user_with_same_email = @user.email.upcase
user_with_same_email.save
```

You should change it for this:

```
user_with_same_email = @user.dup
user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
user_with_same_email.save
```

Answer (score 2):

**Object**

The problem here can be seen with the error itself:

> undefined method `save' for "USER@EXAMPLE.COM":String

The problem you have is *not* that `.save` is unavailable, but that the *object* you're trying to call it on is unable to process it.

The problem is specifically to do with this line:

> user_with_same_email = @user.email.upcase

--

**Fix**

The issue is you're setting the `user_with_same_email` variable as `@user.email.upcase`. You can do what `zishe` suggested (to set the `email` attribute of the new variable)

I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve - as your `User` model sets the email to `downcase` on the `before_save` callback.